# How do I use Powershell to return VM Name, TagName, TagValue in Azure?

Tags: azure-powershell

I'm not very good with parsing and displaying values in hash tables in PowerShell yet.

I want to use command to show the VM name, a specific Tag's name and the value of that tag for that VM.

Something like one of these (even though I know these commands don't work, it's what I'm trying to do):

> `Get-AzResource -Name SYSTEM* -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -TagName BuiltBy | Select Name,TagName,TagValue`

```
Name      TagName   TagValue
----      -------   --------
SYSTEM1   BuiltBy   Frank
SYSTEM2   BuiltBy   Frank
SYSTEM3   BuiltBy   Betty
SYSTEM4   BuiltBy   Frank
```

> `Get-AzResource -Name SYSTEM* -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -TagName BuiltBy | Where {$.TagValue -eq 'Betty'} | Select Name,TagName,TagValue`

```
Name      TagName   TagValue
----      -------   --------
SYSTEM3   BuiltBy   Betty
```

> `Get-AzResource -Name SYSTEM* -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -TagName BuiltBy | Where {$.TagValue -ne 'Frank'} | Select Name,TagName,TagValue`

```
Name      TagName   TagValue
----      -------   --------
SYSTEM3   BuiltBy   Betty
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the PowerShell script for finding VM Name, Tag Name and Tag Value

```
$vmlist=Get-AzResource -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachines'  
foreach( $item in $vmlist){ if($item.Tags.Keys -eq 'CreatedDate' -and $item.Name -eq 'shbhost'){  

  

get-azvm -Name $item.Name |select -Property Name,Tags

  

}}
```

[image]
Output

[image: [enter link description here](https://i.imgur.com/QgMpgS5.png)]